# Is "Have you some water?" a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, do-support, negative-polarity-items, some-any

I believe it same as saying "Do you have some water?"

Is it?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. To help us answer the question, please help us understand why you asked it. Why do you think it is or isn't the same? What attempts have you made to research this, such as by searching for this construction on the web? Since British and American English speakers differ somewhat in the way such questions are framed, what dialect are you interested in? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: There’s a separate issue here when it comes to saying something a native speaker would say. You need to understand the difference between *some* and the corresponding negative-polarity-item *any* as used in questions such as yours. Notice the difference between *“Do you have **any** water?”* on one hand, and *“May I have **some** water?”* on the other. This is rather important. Please see the marked duplicates, and their respective linked questions.

Answer (score 0):

It was once, a long time ago.

The two acceptable versions today would be:

> 1. Have you got some water?

Which is sometimes shortened to "Got some water?" and

> 2. Do you have any water [here]?

Comment: I would suggest that 'Have you any water?' is more idiomatic in a question (c.f. the nursery rhyme 'Baa baa black sheep, have you any wool?'). Answer: 'Yes, I have some'.

Comment: @KateBunting: That nursery rhyme is from the 18th Century. As is the melody.